# Save information from a website using Javascript/Greasemonkey Addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a user/greasemonkey script, that I can add to FireFox. When I visit a particular website, the script will look for defined information, such as

```
<span class="one">INFORMATION</span>
```

Then it will extract the information between the span tags and be sent to a PHP script to add to a MySQL database. I can get by with PHP and MySQL, but I don't know how to create the javascript/greasemonkey element and how to send the information to PHP to add to the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Specifically, you'll set up an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Comment: Will it work as a greasemonkey add on this way? So I instruct it to search for information between a certain span and send it to the PHP script?

Comment: I can't say for sure if this will work with greasemonkey, but if you want to run a PHP script using javascript, that's the way to do it.

For your section question, yes. You probably want to dynamically create a DOM form and send it via POST.